# MLOAD and FastLoad errors: External loader process exited with error [12] and/or [8]

Tags: teradata

Looks like MLOAD is aborting with error code [8], and FastLoad with error code [12]

Tables are not locked for MLOAD, no work tables are present either.
User credentials are valid as well.

This happens in one environment, but runs fine in another.

Curious if you have encountered this, and what could be a good idea to try next.

Loading flat files into 16.x Teradata.

Interesting enough, no load log file is generated.

Comment: Both of those are just return codes, telling you there was an error.  You should also be receiving error codes.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Error 8 are syntax errors in the script aka "user error". MLOAD is quite sensitive to formatting.

Error 12 pertains to so-called "system errors" - when either MLOAD is locked, or Teradata thinks you are attempting a recovery (presence of a backend log table), or FASTLOAD thinks you're in the middle of it when both temp tables are present in the target database.